# Finding the source of flow errors

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I have a JavaScript project that's flow-annotated. When I run `flow` on it, it gives me this error:

```
$ flow 
./layout/layoutTypes.js:48
 48:   type: 'LayerGroup',
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^ string literal `LayerGroup`. Expected string literal `RootLayer`, got `LayerGroup` instead
 57:   type: 'RootLayer',
         ^^^^^^^^^^^ string literal `RootLayer`

./layout/layoutTypes.js:57
 57:   type: 'RootLayer',
             ^^^^^^^^^^^ string literal `RootLayer`. Expected string literal `LayerGroup`, got `RootLayer` instead
 48:   type: 'LayerGroup',
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^ string literal `LayerGroup`

Found 2 errors
```

`layoutTypes.js` is [as such here](https://flowtype.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVBTAHgBzgJwBcxCBPHDMAFW0IEEYBLAcwDsBbDVwgNQEMYAV0oBeMAHIYGKIXFgAPhPwsAFrIUSAxl0IZ8cxeIBWggM6FGUUuIDc6bHiIlylGlkIAZPqT1gxAb1QwZwoALgk3T289cQAadGDGABNw82VWZnjg1j5OVMJ0zISwLHDWQXYAIz0ssFIyiur8WoQGqpqgsBU2pvjO3Xd8wtqoXMYYUgA5XIwhxgzagcIAYTh4fDmFzqg4bgBlRgAvWbBy9ubOgRYOHXDIhmvObn4hDFrKtZSwD7WMPlZaoxCFdNOEflJ-vEAL52TC4AjEMgUMAAJQwmiiPnwfjAgWCSJO4jRGK8WLixWSmyK2RmVL6wVKp0aHWC9SZ5xaPRZXS5F224xgdLAwGAXWwYAIYHwzEqfDAO2xrEQqBh6DhjkRLjApL0AHF8HBBDgcXiQoSdfh9YacOTOpSwGl5tTTrSHQUnfSwJoVOMkvguOELQBtAC60NhDgRZtRcDgmN8AX6LnCRNj8f0nvtjq2NLybuGxVa7N6nW6xY6nW9vv9rED0XwofD9nhTgJ2vrAHUgSplj6YH6uDiLVajRoUWmLRGW5rkRa-J1InPFMT0wpOsODaP5J1x3HJ0A). There's no flow errors when checked individually, but when run locally along with a bunch of other files, it seems to error without a source of error.

What kind of error could this be? How could I expose the source of the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can happen because of flow type inference. Somewhere you have an object that is inferred to be a RootLayer/LayerGroup and flow expects one but sees the other. One way to narrow down where this is happening is to look at a longer "error path." To do that, run:

`flow check --traces 10`

You can use a lower or higher number depending on how deep you want flow to go. This will create a list that shows the path that flow was following when it encountered that particular error. Somewhere (beginning, middle, or towards the end) of that list will be the code that is triggering this. Just go step by step until you find it.